# Fransén-Robinson Constant and an intriguing series

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, constants

Whilst confirming a well known result for the Fransén-Robinson constant $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(x)} dx$ I reduced the calculation to:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi x) \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n+1-x)} dx$$
As I know the goal of my calculations this narrowed down to the following equality:
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n!} \int_{n+1}^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} dx=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-t}}{\pi^2+\log^2(t)} dt$$
Where I am unfortunately stuck. Any help, especially tips, will be well appreciated :)

Comment: It doesn't hold numerically (LHS$\approx 0.0355$, RHS$\approx 0.054$).

Comment: Oh well, unforntunate. I wonder where my mistake was :D In the meantime I used another way to show my result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290733/bromwich-contour-integral-related-to-the-euler-gamma-function. It's just a bit ugly